# Redirecting ampproject URL to original site while implementing amp update-cache

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

I'm trying to implement amp update cache, but facing issue while accessing 
"apikey.pub" amp-project URL.

```
https://www-example-in.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.example.in/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub
```

redirecting to

```
www.example.in/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub
```

I also try with

```
https://www-example-in.cdn.ampproject.org/r/s/www.example.in/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub
```

it's show error:

```
The requested URL /r/s/www.example.in/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub was not found on this server.
```

I have already put my public key on `www.example.in/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub`.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

the address `./well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub` is an address on your website to store public key of signiture and must return text/plain header on response. you are try to make it on amp cache server!

Comment: @Vishal Kamal. why you are try to accessing "apikey.pub" amp-project URL. you do not need access this url. if you have the file on your host amp-project crawler will access it on your host to unlock your sent signiture for update-cache request

Comment: show error details and error throw scenario please to check it